# How to handle click event of Mupdf in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, mupdf

I am using Mupdf plugin for annotation in Xamarin. I want to save the annotated area in db, for that I want to handle Mupdf Ink Button event. But I am not able to get button event. I tried looking in to Metadata file but did not get anything.

This is the code in MetadataЖ

```
[Register("OnInkButtonClick", "(Landroid/view/View;)V", "GetOnInkButtonClick_Landroid_view_View_Handler")] 
public virtual void OnInkButtonClick(View p0);
```

How can I use this method as a Click event?

This is the code which I have used to display pdf:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(SettingsVariables.appSettings.docCurrPath);
var intent0 = new Intent(this, typeof(MuPDFActivity));
//intent0.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
intent0.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
intent0.SetData(uri);
StartActivity(intent0);
```

Comment: Please could include any code that you have tried so far

Comment: @RobForrest This is the code in Metadata..   [Register("OnInkButtonClick", "(Landroid/view/View;)V", "GetOnInkButtonClick_Landroid_view_View_Handler")]
        public virtual void OnInkButtonClick(View p0);       But I am not getting..How to use this method as a Click event

Comment: Please add the code to your question and include anything that you have tried so far.

Comment: fixed typos, improved formatting